# Setup custom nameservers or set an A record

Tags: vps, domain-name, nameservers, a-records

What is the best practice to point a domain name to a VPS, setup custom nameservers or set an A record?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to set up your private nameservers. This is the advantage of VPS, so no need to have it and not use it:)

Besides, personal DNS look a lot more professional.

In addition, while setting up personal DNS, do not forget to create glue records (this can be done at the side of domain registrar). Once done, you may proceed and add A records at the side of your VPS hosting provider.

Hope, this helps :)